# Mini Binary Tree "library"

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-search

This is my first attempt at learning binary trees. I'm looking for general feedback on how it could be made cleaner, more idiomatic, or more efficient.

```
data Tree a = ETree | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) a deriving (Show)

tInsert :: Ord o => o -> Tree o -> Tree o
tInsert x ETree = Node ETree ETree x
tInsert x (Node lT rT a)
    | x < a = Node (tInsert x lT) rT a
    | x > a = Node lT (tInsert x rT) a
    | otherwise = Node lT rT x

-- Folds a list into a tree
tFromListL, tFromListR :: Ord o => [o] -> Tree o
tFromListL = foldl (flip tInsert) ETree
tFromListR = foldr tInsert ETree

-- Turns a tree into a list
tToList :: Ord o => Tree o -> [o]
tToList ETree = []
tToList (Node lT rT a) = (tToList lT) ++ [a] ++ (tToList rT)

-- Splits a list roughly in half (as part of balancing)
splitInHalf :: [a] -> ([a],[a])
splitInHalf xs = splitAt (round $ (fromIntegral $ length xs) / 2.0) xs

-- Returns how unbalanced a node is
tUnbalancedBy :: Tree a -> Int
tUnbalancedBy ETree = 0
tUnbalancedBy (Node lT rT _) = absDiff (tDepth lT) (tDepth rT)

-- Arranges a list in such a way that it forms a more balanced tree
balanceList :: [a] -> [a]
balanceList xs = let (fH,sH) = splitInHalf xs in (reverse fH) ++ sH

-- "Inefficient balance"
tIneffBalance :: Ord o => Tree o -> Tree o
tIneffBalance = tFromListL . balanceList . tToList

-- Finds the min/max values of a tree
tMin, tMax :: Ord o => Tree o -> o
tMin ETree = error "tMin called on an Empty Tree"
tMin (Node lT _ a) = case lT of
    ETree           -> a
    (Node lT' _ _)  -> tMin lT'

tMax ETree = error "tMax called on an Empty Tree"
tMax (Node _ rT a) = case rT of
    ETree           -> a
    (Node _ rT' _)  -> tMax rT'

-- Find the max depth of a tree 
tDepth :: Tree a -> Int
tDepth ETree = 0
tDepth (Node lT rT _) = 1 + max (tDepth lT) (tDepth rT)

-- Finds how many nodes a tree contains
tSize :: Tree a -> Int
tSize ETree = 0
tSize (Node lT rT _) = 1 + (tSize lT) + (tSize rT)

absDiff :: Int -> Int -> Int
absDiff x y = abs $ x - y

-- Checks if a node is balanced
tIsBalanced :: Tree a -> Bool
tIsBalanced ETree = True
tIsBalanced n
    | tUnbalancedBy n > 2 = False
    | otherwise = True

-- Checks if a value is an element of the tree
tElem :: Ord o => o -> Tree o -> Bool
tElem x ETree = False
tElem x (Node lT rT a)
    | x < a = tElem x lT
    | x > a = tElem x rT
    | otherwise = True

tDelete :: Ord o => o -> Tree o -> Tree o
tDelete _ ETree = ETree
tDelete _ n@(Node ETree ETree _) = n -- Or give "Not found" error?
tDelete tD n@(Node lT rT a)
    | tD < a = Node (tDelete tD lT) rT a
    | tD > a = Node lT (tDelete tD rT) a
    | otherwise = case (lT,rT) of
        (ETree,t)   -> t
        (t,ETree)   -> t
        (t,t')      -> let fMin = tMin t' in Node t (tDelete (tMin t') t') fMin
```

My main concerns are:

- The balancing algorithm. I thought it would work beautifully at first, then I realized that it basically just turns the tree into a "V". It's more efficient then a linked list, but still not very balanced
- The 2 "tToList*" functions. Should I use foldl or foldr? They seem to act fairly equivalently; although foldl is easier to use because you typically read a list from the left
- The "tDelete" function. It works (from my testing), but it looks very ugly. I basically just wrote it case-by-case, which made it very long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Function Visibility

In the code there's some functions that seem to be intended for internal use only. To hide these from external modules you should have a "proper" module declaration that exports those functions you want to make "public".

```
module MyTree ( Tree(ETree, Node), tInsert, tFromListL, tFromListR, ... ) where
```

this allows you to hide (and change) implementation details of your exposed function.

#### Balancing Your Tree

Your algorithm to balance that tree is something along the lines of \$\mathcal{O}(3 * n)\$. That's **bad** compared to an almost constant time-effort when balancing in tree form. Then again why are you even exposing this functionality?

If you allow a tree to be unbalanced, you shouldn't expose an operation to balance it and vice versa. You should **strongly** consider extracting balanced behaviour into either a separate type and using `instance` to expose a common "interface" or extract this into a completely separate module.

Something like this:

```
class (Ord a) => Tree a where
    tInsert, tDelete :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a
    tElem :: a -> Tree a -> Bool
    tIsBalanced :: Tree a -> Bool
    tSize, tDepth :: Tree a -> Int
    tMin, tMax :: Tree a -> a
    tToList :: Tree a -> [a]

data BalancedTree a = Empty | Node (BalancedTree a) (BalancedTree a) a deriving (Show)

instance NormalTree BalancedTree where
-- | because we are an instance of NormalTree we can access tInsert'
    tInsert = balance . tInsert'
-- and so on and so forth

data NormalTree a = Empty | Node (Tree a) (Tree a) a deriving (Show)

instance Tree NormalTree where
    tInsert = tInsert'

    -- | default implementation for insert without balancing
    tInsert' :: a -> Tree a -> Tree a
```

> Note that I haven't even used this myself and I'm not sure whether
>   this works. The code should give you a gist as to how this could /
>   should work and isn't even intended to be syntactically correct.

This defines the "interface" of Tree in a `class` and then uses `data` types to implement said "interface".

#### Errors In Expected Circumstances

When you call `tMax` or `tMin` respectively on an `ETree` (which would be better named as `Empty`) an `error` is raised. That's an IMO really ugly and declarative way of solving this. It'd be preferrable to have a pure function. This requires a small change to the type-signature:

```
tMin, tMax :: Ord o => Tree o -> Maybe o
```

Which in turn allows you to do the following:

```
tMin Empty = Nothing
tMin (Node lT _ a) = case lT of 
    Empty -> a
    (Node lT' _ _) -> tMin lT'
```

This function is total and pure. As such it's much easier and cleaner to use.